# How to select all recods from 1 table, and a computed value from another table, and display all results

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

How do I select all records from one table, plus a computed value from another table (Like average), and display all results including those from the first table with out corresponding value from second table?

I have tried this

```
SELECT
table1.*,
AVG(table2.column) AS average
FROM table1
JOIN 
table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

But it only displays only results with average.

What should I do please?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, please. Not images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve ur problem....

```
 SELECT *,
    (select AVG(table2.column) FROM table2 where table1.id = table2.id) AS average
    from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query to fetch the details.

```
SELECT table1.*,
    (SELECT AVG(table2.column) FROM table2 WHERE table1.pkid = table2.fkid) as Average
FROM table1;
```